# comparable alternative to Nodebox for a graph theory project using Python? (fancy graph visualization with gradient, shadowstroke and so on)

Tags: python, visualization, graph-theory

since Nodebox Libraries are only fruit-friendly... (Graph Library in Nodebox2 is far simpler)

i'm trying with Matplotlib, Graphviz... but you know, they are too serious for something like this:
[a graph visualization using nodebox](http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Graph)

there is really nothing comparable in windows world?

Comment: Nodebox for OpenGL? http://www.cityinabottle.org/nodebox/ Supposed to be cross platform. Haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried networkx?  I haven't tried it myself but as far as I've read its more powerful than nodebox.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/networkx/

I see in their download page they mention Windows : )